# Retrieve city name from TimeZone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I have set my default timezone as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)

```
class Application < Rails::Application
 config.time_zone = "Asia/Kolkata"
end
```

now from rails console I can get timezone as `IST` but instead of this I want to get identifier of this timezone(`Asia/Kolkata`).

Here is what I get:

```
 > Time.zone.name # work for this
 => "Asia/Kolkata" 
 > Time.now.zone
 => "IST" 
 > Time.now.zone.name # this doesn't work
 => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "IST":String
```

Now I am getting trouble here:

```
 > b
 => 2015-03-13 16:38:12 +0530
 > b.zone
 => "IST"
 > b.zone.name
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "IST":String
```

Is there any way to retrieved `zone.name` (here `Asia/Kolkata`) from object `b`.

**Note:** I don't want only for this `IST` timezone. But for universal timezone. This is just one sample. Is there any way or gem which solve my problem?? I appreciate for your help and guide.

### Update

If I define `timezone` in application.rb then PrakshMurthy's asnwer is correct. But I don't want for specific timezone. So I have to implement without specifying in **application.rb**. Please help me.

Comment: What does `b.time_zone` give?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy That will work.. I tested. It is giving the object of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy `NoMethodError: undefined method `time_zone' for 2015-03-13 16:38:12 +0530:Time`

Comment: @HetalKhunti You error is telling it is `Time` object.. **0530:Time** ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for (without specifying in **application.rb** for specific `timezone`)

```
   > b
   => 2015-03-13 16:38:12 +0530
   > getutc = b.utc_offset
   => 19800
   > tz_names = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect{|z| z.tzinfo.name if z.utc_offset == getutc}.compact!
   => ["Asia/Kolkata", "Asia/Kolkata", "Asia/Kolkata", "Asia/Kolkata", "Asia/Colombo"] 
   > tz_names.first
   => "Asia/Kolkata"
```

Now You don't have to specifying default timezone in **application.rb**. :)

Comment: This answer helped me, but #zones_map is now a private method.
It worked when I replaced ".zones_map.values" with ".all"

Answer (score 3):

This should work: `b.in_time_zone.time_zone`

Comment: @Prakash : If I remove `config.time_zone = "Asia/Kolkata"` from application.rb  then I get only "UTC" now can not get the same result. I have to remove this default timezone as my app for glob. Not for India only.

Answer (score 1):

`b.time_zone.name`

Since your `b` is something like `Time.zone.now` and `b.time_zone.name` gives `Asia/Kolkata` . Also `b.time_zone.name.to_s` gives same result.

Comment: Some words explaining your answer would be helpful.